# comma seperated string to array issue with split() method

Tags: javascript

suppose I have a string which has values

```
var str = 'abc, abc, inc.,  abd'
```

and I want to split this string to array and problem here is abc, inc and i want it print abc,inc. as one element in array. this whole is a string so that if i use split function it gets separated and we can use by giving var str = 'abc,"abc, inc.",abd' but is there way to split string without this two. We can use the second one but problem is what if I have strings more than 50? Please help me with this i am new to coding.

Comment: How is it supposed to know which commas are delimiters and which are not? This seems more like a natural language processing problem.

Comment: _"what if I have strings more than 50?"_ What does 50 have to do with anything?

Comment: For suppose we have strings 'a, b, c,inc. ,,, so on if we other 50 string' we can't go on giving "a, inc." to every comma string right. That is my point sir

Comment: You need to try constructing a regular expression based on your requirement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Quantifiers

Answer (score 1):

First split your string at the commas, then compare the looped value to your target value. If there is a match, use the keys to get the previous value, concatenate the previous and current values together, then use splice to replace the current value with the concatenated value using the keys. Return the newly formatted array.

If this is not what you're looking for, let me know and I can change or remove this answer.

```js
const str = 'abc, abc, inc.,  abd, fgh, jhg,   uiy, inc., yhg,   okj, inc., abc, xyz, inc., mkj, fgh, jhg,   uiy, inc., yhg, abc, inc.,  abd, fgh,yhg,   okj, inc., abc, fjb, inc., lgb '

const evalStr = (str) => {
  // split the string at the commas and create an array o those split values
  const results = str.split(',')
  // loop over the keys & values 
  results.map((a, k) => {
    // compare the value trimmed value 
    a.trim() === 'inc.'
      // we have a match
      // using the keys we get the previous value and current value
      // and concatenate and format the string
      // splice the value starting at the previous value and span 2 values
      // trim white space
      ? results.splice(k - 1, 2, `${results[k-1].trim()},${a.trim()}`) 
      : null
    // if we wish to trim all white space...
    results.splice(k, 1, results[k].trim())  
  })
  return results
}

console.log(evalStr(str))
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var str = 'abc,abc,inc,abd';
let fun= str.split(" "); //Gap in Between will help you get the 
console.log(fun);
```

Comment: This won't work sir my question is that i want to print abc,inc. as one array element

Answer (score -1):

Here is the simple use of 'split', 'map' and 'trim' (for remove spacing) function that can achieve your gole.

```js
var str = 'abc, abc, inc.,  abd'
str = str.split(',');
var arr = [...new Set(str.map(item=>item.trim()))];
console.log(arr.toString())
```

Comment: This not my question is about sir. I want to print abc,inc. as one element in the array because that whole is a string

Comment: so you can user toString method to convert array to the string. i have updated the code

Comment: no actually str is a string and i need to convert them to array in which abc, inc. need to be as one element. If i use split(',') it is separating that string as well